# Get-QADUser for users outside dn?

Tags: powershell, active-directory-group, quest

Hi when I run in PowerShell (with the Quest AD add-in) a simple

```
Get-QADUser -displayname "John, Doe Jr."
```

It works for everyone who is in my dn, e.g. "europe", as soon as I try this on someone outside e.g. asia or africa it returns nothing.

How can I get this to work to return me also their details when i only have their display name?

Comment: I am not familiar with Quest Cmdlets or have a multidomain environment to test with but could you use `-UseGlobalCatalog` in your example. See [here](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Get-QADUser). Understand that you will get a limited set of attributes when using the GC.

Comment: Do you try to use `-SearchRoot IdentityParameter` advaced option ?

Comment: @Matt yes tried that first no difference

Comment: @Matt amaziningly this now works, tried that  a lot of times, not output but now suddenly ... presto, dont get it, but ... happy :)